# The expenses of a postdoctoral fellow

Tags: research-process, postdocs, career-path, projects, fees

I am a postdoctoral fellow on applied mathematics and I am applying for a scholarship, they asked to estimate the expenses of the scholarship. My laboratory pay for me the conferences, so do you have any suggestions that are useful for my carrier? my project concerns problems related to air transport industry.

Comment: Office/lab + equipment + travel + conference

Comment: Books, papers, memberships. You're on you own for beer, though..

Comment: @Buffy it depends on the funder. You shouldn't probably mention it explicitly in the proposal, but it can be a solid travel expense ;)

Comment: good to suggest books though, especially in maths!

Comment: @fqq the travels should be for the project I am applying for, so I am searching for ideas on training, creation of business plan beacuse the conferences are supported by my lab